# .htaccess or PHP change url

Tags: php, .htaccess, iframe, url-rewriting

Currently my .htaccess file reads:

```
DirectoryIndex dice.php
```

Dice.php is a loading page which has an iframe in (index.php) which eventually when finished loading breaks the iframe and fills the page. However it fills it as https://example.com/index.php in the url.

I want it to fill as https://example.com/play.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Dagon make https://example.com/index.php appear as https://example.com/play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^play/?$    index.php    [NC,L]
```